# Build TypeDescriptor with annotations for Class

Tags: java, spring

I'm using a ConditionalConverter that should match with

```
@Override
public boolean matches(TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
  return sourceType.hasAnnotation(Document.class);
}
```

But here, sourceType.hasAnnotation(Document.class) return false even if provided class is for instance :

```
@Document
class Person {}
```

If I look what's behind, TypeDescriptor creation from Class payed no attention to annotations :

```
public static TypeDescriptor valueOf(Class<?> type) {
    if (type == null) {
        type = Object.class;
    }
    TypeDescriptor desc = commonTypesCache.get(type);
    return (desc != null ? desc : new TypeDescriptor(ResolvableType.forClass(type), null, null));
}
```

For more information, the call to the converter is done via
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService.canConvert(Class sourceType, Class targetType)

Codes from Spring are from 4.2.8.RELEASE

Don't know how to make my Converter working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleeping on the issue, I finally ended up using the underlying Class to test annotation existence.

```
@Override
public boolean matches(TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
  return sourceType.getObjectType().isAnnotationPresent(Document.class);
}
```

Comment: Sleeping on issues is always positive ;)